# Converting Cisco IOS output to XML

Tags: python, parsing, xml, networking

The **INPUT FILE** is created by a script that runs "show interface description | i FN" against each of my routers.

Once I have that file, my **PYTHON SCRIPT** below, parses the **INPUT FILE** for each of the routers hostnames and appends the circuit carrier acronym (VZ, BT, Cogent...etc) and hostname to the **OUTPUT FILE** in XML format using elementtree.

It works! But due to my lack of scripting skills its ugly. Each time I want to add a new IF statement, I just add it below the previous line. Can anyone show me how to properly consolidate this logic into a cleaner script? For example: I run "if text.find("FN=@WAN")!=-1" and then a whole new set of if statements for "if text.find("FN=@MAN")!=-1"

**INPUT FILE ("exampleFile912.txt"):**

```
h_name:rtr07001:show int desc | i FN
Gi0/0/0                        up             up       FN=@WAN, [VZ_10M], RE=MPLS
Gi0/0/0.25                     up             up       FN=@WAN, [VZ_10M], RE=MPLS
Gi0/0/1                        up             up       FN=@INL, ID=G0/1, RE=USW
Gi0/0/2                        up             up       FN=@INL, ID=G0/0/2, RE=RTR
rtr07001#
h_name:rtr07002:show int desc | i FN
Gi0/0/0                        up             up       FN=@WAN,[BT_10M], RE=MPLS
Gi0/0/0.30                     up             up       FN=@WAN, [BT_10M], RE=MPLS
Gi0/0/1                        up             up       FN=@INL, ID=G0/1, RE=USW
Gi0/0/2                        up             up       FN=@INL, ID=G0/0/2, RE=RTR
rtr07002#
h_name:rtr05001:show int desc | i FN
Gi0/0/0                        up             up       FN=@WAN, [VZ_30M], RE=MPLS
Gi0/0/0.25                     up             up       FN=@WAN, [VZ_30M], RE=MPLS
Gi0/0/1                        up             up       FN=@INL,  ID=G1/0/1,  RE=USW
Gi0/0/2                        up             up       FN=@INL, ID=G1/0, RE=RTR
RTR05001#
FINISHED
```

**PYTHON SCRIPT:**

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree
from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree
import time
import os
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et

def make():
    readMe = open('goingtoxml.xml','w')
    readMe.write("<go></go>")
    readMe.close`


 def main():
    base_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    xml_file = os.path.join(base_path, "goingtoxml.xml")
    tree = et.parse(xml_file)
    root = tree.getroot()`

with open("exampleFile912.txt", "r") as fh1:
        while True:
                text = fh1.readline()
                if 'h_name' in text:
                        start1 = text.find("h_name:")
                        end1 = text.find(":show")
                        hname = (text[start1+7:end1])
                        print hname
                        new_product = et.SubElement(root, "device", attrib={"id": hname})
                if text.find("0.")!=-1:
                        continue
                if text.find("VPN")!=-1:
                        continue
                if text.find("FN=@WAN")!=-1:
                        if text.find("[V")!=-1:
                                new_prod_name = et.SubElement(new_product, "Carrier" )
                                new_prod_desc = et.SubElement(new_product, "Speed")
                                new_prod_name.text = 'Vz'
                                new_prod_desc.text = 'test'
                        if text.find("BT")!=-1:
                                new_prod_name = et.SubElement(new_product, "Carrier" )
                                new_prod_desc = et.SubElement(new_product, "Speed")
                                new_prod_name.text = 'BT'
                                new_prod_desc.text = 'test'
                        if text.find("[Li")!=-1:
                                new_prod_name = et.SubElement(new_product, "Carrier" )
                                new_prod_desc = et.SubElement(new_product, "Speed")
                                new_prod_name.text = 'Lightower'
                                new_prod_desc.text = 'test'
                        if text.find("[Lv")!=-1:
                                new_prod_name = et.SubElement(new_product, "Carrier" )
                                new_prod_desc = et.SubElement(new_product, "Speed")
                                new_prod_name.text = 'Lv3'
                                new_prod_desc.text = 'test'
                        if text.find("ATT")!=-1:
                                new_prod_name = et.SubElement(new_product, "Carrier" )
                                new_prod_desc = et.SubElement(new_product, "Speed")
                                new_prod_name.text = 'ATT'
                if text.find("FN=@MAN")!=-1:
                        if text.find("[V")!=-1:
                                new_prod_name = et.SubElement(new_product, "Carrier" )
                                new_prod_desc = et.SubElement(new_product, "Speed")
                                new_prod_name.text = 'Vz'
                                new_prod_desc.text = 'test'
                        if text.find("BT")!=-1:
                                new_prod_name = et.SubElement(new_product, "Carrier" )
                                new_prod_desc = et.SubElement(new_product, "Speed")
                                new_prod_name.text = 'BT'
                                new_prod_desc.text = 'test'
                        if text.find("[Li")!=-1:
                                new_prod_name = et.SubElement(new_product, "Carrier" )
                                new_prod_desc = et.SubElement(new_product, "Speed")
                                new_prod_name.text = 'Lightower'
                                new_prod_desc.text = 'test'
                        if text.find("[Lv")!=-1:
                                new_prod_name = et.SubElement(new_product, "Carrier" )
                                new_prod_desc = et.SubElement(new_product, "Speed")
                                new_prod_name.text = 'Lv3'
                                new_prod_desc.text = 'test'
                        if text.find("ATT")!=-1:
                                new_prod_name = et.SubElement(new_product, "Carrier" )
                                new_prod_desc = et.SubElement(new_product, "Speed")
                                new_prod_name.text = 'ATT'
                                new_prod_desc.text = 'test'
                        if text.find("[C")!=-1:
                                new_prod_name = et.SubElement(new_product, "Carrier" )
                                new_prod_desc = et.SubElement(new_product, "Speed")
                                new_prod_name.text = 'Cogent'
                                new_prod_desc.text = 'test'
                        if text.find("[A")!=-1:
                                new_prod_name = et.SubElement(new_product, "Carrier" )
                                new_prod_desc = et.SubElement(new_product, "Speed")
                                new_prod_name.text = 'AboveNet'
                                new_prod_desc.text = 'test'


                        tree.write(xml_file)

                        for child in root:
                                print(child.tag, child.attrib)
                if 'FINISHED' in text:
                        break

make()
main()
```

**OUTPUT FILE ("goingtoxml.xml"):**

```
<go>
<device id="rtr07001">
<Carrier>Vz</Carrier>
<Speed>test</Speed>
</device>
<device id="rtr07002">
<Carrier>BT</Carrier>
<Speed>test</Speed>
</device>
<device id="rtr05001">
<Carrier>Vz</Carrier>
<Speed>test</Speed>
</device>
<device id="rtr05002">
<Carrier>BT</Carrier>
<Speed>test</Speed>
</device>
</go>
```

Comment: I think your `main()` function got screwed up by a formatting error

Comment: You have a ` (a backtick) at the end of `readMe.close`. It should be `readMe.close()`.